# Need help solving this loop in MIPS(assembly)

Tags: loops, assembly, mips

I have a loop in MIPS(assembly) that looks like this:

```
LOOP: 
      slt $t2, $0, $t1
      beq $t2, $0, DONE
      subi $t1, $t1, 1
      addi $s2, $s2, 2
      j LOOP
DONE:
```

If the value of `$t1` is set to 10 in the beginning, what is the value of `$s2` if `$s2` is set to ZERO in the beginning?

I tried to solve the answer to the question and I'm getting 20. But, the solutions manual says its 200. Can anyone tell me what im missing out here? Won't `$s2` keep getting incremented by 2 until `$t1` is 0?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that you're correct, i.e. the answer is 20 and not 200.

Comment: any idea how can I output $s2 in this?

Comment: Just use a debugger/simulator. It is 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Joe Farrell, this loop is basically equivalent to this C-style loop:

```
while(t1 > 0)
{
  --t1;
  s2 += 2;
}
```

Looks like you're working out of the book "Computer Organization and Design: The Hardware/Software Interface" I only managed to find errata sheets for 3rd and 4th editions, and I didn't see this typo addressed in either. Which edition are you using?

Comment: yeah, that is exactly what i thought too.
using the 5th edition right now, which is the latest one (2014)

Comment: upon research, ive realized the solution manual is full of mistakes..talk about waste of a bill

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be 22. Because if u repeat the loop till t1 = -1, s2 would be 22, and when the loop starts again t2 becomes 0 which leads in printing DONE, which is where the loop exits.